# Objective C autorelease

Tags: objective-c, autorelease

Hello I do not fully understand the autorelease function call in obj-C.

```
@interface A{
id obj;
}

@implementation A

-(void)myMethod;
{
obj = [BaseObj newObj];           //where newObj is a method like :[[[BaseObj alloc]init]autorelease];
}

-(void)anotherMehtod;
{
[obj someMeth];                     //this sometimes gives me EXC_BAD_ACCESS
}

@end
```

So to solve this I put a retain. Now do I need to release this object manually if i retain it?

Comment: A side note: the rule in Cocoa is that if a method name starts with `new`, `copy`, `retain`, or `alloc`, the caller must send `release` or `autorelease` to balance it. So a method named `newObj` ought not to autorelease its own result.

Answer (score 4):

If you are the **owner** of an object - is your responsibility to release it.

You become owner of an object if you've done at least one of the following:

- instantiated it through `alloc`
- passed `retain`
- passed `copy`

For more details read [Object Ownership and Disposal](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-BEHDEDDB)

Comment: You forgot `new`, so if `+newObj` would follow the guidelines the object shouldn't even be auto-released in the first place.

Comment: @ Georg Fritzsche: `new` is the same as `[[aClass alloc] init];`. Therefore, to mention `alloc` only is enaugh. `+newObj` from description already contain postponed `release` pass: `alloc]init]autorelease]`, so there is no need for additional `release` here

Comment: And of course `obj` will be already released in `anotherMehtod`, that's why EXC_BAD_ACCESS result

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The rule is, if you **retain** an object, you are also responsible of releasing it in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Like all other static methods in Obj-C `[BaseObj newObj]` only exists in your method `-(void)myMethod` at the end of this method (roughly) `obj` gets `-release` message from autorelease pool.

If you want to preserve this object - use `[[BaseObj newObj] retain]` or `[BaseObj alloc] init]` and release it in `-dealloc` or when you has to.

For example:

```
@interface A{
  id obj;
}

@implementation A

-(void)myMethod
{
  [obj autorelease];
  obj = [[BaseObj newObj] retain];           //where newObj is a method like :[[[BaseObj alloc]init]autorelease];
}

-(void)anotherMehtod;
{
  [obj someMeth];                     //this sometimes gives me EXC_BAD_ACCESS
}

-(void)dealloc
{
  [obj release];
  [super dealloc];
}

@end
```